# How to keep leading spaces in merge fields (MS Word)

Tags: python, ms-word, mailmerge, mergefield, docx-mailmerge

I have problem with merge field in word document , i created merge field like this:

```
{ MERGEFIELD string_data }
```

I try to add some text to the merge field with leading space, example: **"       Test String"**
after I added the value to merge field the result is **"Test String"** the merge field eliminating the leading space,

I'm used python to fill the merge field:

```
from mailmerge import MailMerge
def main():
   temp = "string.docx"
   str_data = "  Test String"
   doc = MailMerge(temp)
   doc.merge(string_data=str_data)
   file_name = "out_string.docx"
   doc.write(file_name)
```

is there a way to keep leading space in merge field ?

Thanks

Comment: From what you've posted, it seems you're not actually doing a mailmerge - all you're doing is changing the text displayed by various mergefields. You might consider using Word Content Controls instead.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'm used python mail merge for fill the merge field 
from mailmerge import MailMerge


`def main():
    temp = "string.docx"'
    str_data = "  Test String"
    doc = MailMerge(temp)
    doc.merge(string_data=str_data)
    file_name = "out_string.docx"
    doc.write(file_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`

Comment: All that confirms is that you're not doing a mailmerge. Mailmerge functionality is built into Word and requires no programming. All you're doing is using mergefields as placeholder for where you want to populate a document. What you're doing can just as easily be done using bookmarks, content controls, formfields, document properties, document variables, etc.